# check getIntent().getStringExtra(View_name.value_id)

Tags: android, string, if-statement

I passes variable from Activity A to Activity B

I have problem :/

When a variable is empty it is error.
When a variable is not empty it without error.

I check this:

```
if (   getIntent().getStringExtra(View_name.value_id).equals(null)  ){
          textView1.setText(" bla bla bla");
        }
    else{   
          textView1.setText("ble ble ble"); 
         }
```

please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this line of code:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra(View_name.value_id).equals(null)
```

Think about what you're doing here. You trying to call the method "equals" on null.
Instead, you could change this to

```
getIntent().getStringExtra(View_name.value_id) == null
```

Or, even better, try this:

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra(View_name.value_id)) // true if the key exists
```

Answer (score 1):

Use getIntent().hasExtra(name) to check if the extra exists, instead of checking if it's null.